# Why instead of json-object answer I get a "404 not found" response?

Tags: json, ajax, spring-boot, jackson, thymeleaf

Please help me. Why instead of json-object answer I get a "404 not found" response?

I am sending a following json-object to the server:

```
let dayEvent = { "dateEvent": "someEvent" };
$.ajax({
    url: "/day",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(dayEvent),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#response").text("Success: " + data);
}).fail(function (e) {
$("#response").text("Error: " + e); });
```

Further this controller processes the json-object:

```
@RestController
public class TaskExistController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", value="/day")
    public String dayEvent(@RequestBody TaskDataModel day) {

        System.out.println(day.getDateEvent());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(day.getDateEvent());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

TaskDataModel code:

```
public class TaskDataModel {
String dateEvent;

public void setDateEvent(String dateEvent) {
    this.dateEvent = dateEvent;
}

public String getDateEvent() {
    return dateEvent;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TaskDataModel [dateEvent=" + dateEvent + "]";
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that your Spring server application is running on http://localhost:8080.
Therefore, try:  
`url: "http://localhost:8080/day"`

I also see that you use contentType application/json, and on serverside you declare:
`produces="application/json"` but not `consumes="application/json"`
However, this is not the reason of the 404, but something you could consider to add.

It's also good to know that instantiating an ObjectMapper is relatively expensive. So it is better to declare one on class level, instead of each time your endpoint is being called.

Comment: New link not resolved the problem. Maybe the matter in the incompatibilities of dependencies? I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, postgresql, jackson-databind. Just a week ago code worked.

Comment: so what did you change since a week ago then? I assume you also have the spring-boot-starter-web depencency? And can you confirm that the server is running on http://localhost:8080?

Comment: I just created a Spring Boot application and used your code examples for the controller and taskDataModel. When I do a POST-call from postman, it works..

Comment: Server is running, the json object is being sent successfully, but the response from the server is 404. I just added an entity to work with the database, and I wanted to connect everything with UI, but failed

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your REST url wrong?
Maybe change your server url to (`http://localhost:8080`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/day",
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(dayEvent),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: yes. Maybe the matter in the incompatibilities of dependencies? I use spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, hibernate-entitymanager, spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf, postgresql, jackson-databind. Just a week ago code

Comment: Can you provide your application.yml or application.properties? Is your port really 8080?

Comment: There is nothing written about the port 8080, only settings for connection to postgresql

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/EventManager
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Answer (score 0):

Add consumes to your end point to accept JSON

```
consumes = "application/json"
```